# spring webflux how to manage sequential business logic code in reactive world

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is this approach is reactive friendly?

I have a reactive controller "save" method calling myService.save(request).

The service layer needs to:

1. jdbc save(on another scheduler because code is blocking),
2. generate a template string (on another scheduler),
3. send an email(on another scheduler),
4. finally return the saved entity to the controller layer

I can't chain all my calls in one pipeline or I don't know how to achieve this, because I want to send back (1) that is lost as soon as I do ....flatMap(templateService::generateStringTemplate) for example.

So instead I trigger my sub operations inside (1).

Is it how am I supposed to handle this or is there a clever way to do it in one pipeline ?

Below code to support the question. Thanks.

**Service called by Controller layer**

```
    public Mono<Prospect> save(final Prospect prospect) {

    return Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
                Prospect savedProspect = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> prospectRepository.save(prospect));

                templateService.generateProspectSubscription(savedProspect)
                        .map(t ->
                                EmailPostRequest.builder()
                                       ...
                                        .build())
                        .flatMap(emailService::send)
                        .subscribe();

                return savedProspect;
            })
            .subscribeOn(jdbcScheduler);

}
```

**TemplateService**

```
public Mono<String> generateProspectSubscription(final Prospect prospect) {        
    return Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
               ...

                Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(WELCOME_EN_FTL);
                String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, model);
                return html;
            }
    ).subscribeOn(freemarkerScheduler);
}
```

**EmailService**

```
 public Mono<Void> send(final EmailPostRequest e) {

    return Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
                MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper mimeHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                        MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());


                mimeHelper.setTo(e.getTo());
                mimeHelper.setText(e.getText(), true);
                mimeHelper.setSubject(e.getSubject());
                mimeHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(e.getFrom(), e.getPersonal()));

                emailSender.send(message);

                return Mono.empty();
            }
    ).subscribeOn(emailScheduler).then();
}
```

**EDITED SERVICE**
I think this version of service layer is cleaner but any comments is appreciated

```
    public Mono<Prospect> save(final Prospect prospect) {

    return Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> transactionTemplate.execute(status -> prospectRepository.save(prospect)))
            .subscribeOn(jdbcScheduler)
            .flatMap(savedProspect -> {
                        templateService.generateProspectSubscription(savedProspect)
                                .map(t ->
                                        EmailPostRequest.builder()
                                                ...
                                                .build())
                                .flatMap(emailService::send)
                                .subscribe();

                        return Mono.just(savedProspect);
                    }
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is not reactive friendly, as you're 100% wrapping blocking libraries.
With this use case, you can't really see the benefit of a reactive runtime and chances are the performance of your application is worse than a blocking one.

If your main motivation is performance, than this is probably counter-productive.
Offloading a lot of blocking I/O work on to specialized `Schedulers` has a runtime cost in term of memory (creating more threads) and CPU (context switching). If performance and scalability are your primary concern, then switching to Spring MVC and leveraging the `Flux`/`Mono` support where it fits, or even calling `block()` operators is probably a better fit.

If your main motivation is using a specific library, like Spring Framework's `WebClient` with Spring MVC, then you're better off using `.block()` operators in selected places rather than wrapping and scheduling everything.

Comment: Thanks Brian, really appreciate your feedback. Can you please clarify your 2nd paragraph a bit please? At the moment I'm using reactive webflux. Are you suggesting to still use it but call `.block()` instead of delegating the blocking code to a specialized scheduler (are we not supposed to "never" block the event loop thread)? Or are you suggesting (in the case where most of my business logic is blocking) to switch back to spring-mvc? I thought that with this mixed approach I would still benefit from a non blocking system, at least on lower level layers like network/rest.

Comment: the HTTP layer is more efficient, but it looks like that gain is more than erased by all the scheduling that you have to deal with here.